# SSIS Derived Column Transformation

Tags: ssis

I am trying to develop a package which takes a string (in the format 1.02.3.04 or 01.02.03.4 and lots of other permutations) and amends this based upon the following rules

1. if the second character is a "." then pad the first group with a 0
   FINDSTRING([mycolname],".",1) returns the position of the first "." and for all values of 2 then apply this rule and amend the string eg if 1.2.3.4 will return 2 the string should be 01.2.3.4
2. if the second instance of "." is 5 FINDSTRING([mycolname],".",2) then add a 0 in after the third character eg 01.02.3.4
3. if the third instance of "." is 8 FINDSTRING([mycolname],".",3) then add 0 in after the 6th character

I am a little stuck with some of the logic !

anyone help ??

Comment: Just to be clear, are you applying each rule sequentially? So, check the first rule first and change the string, then check the second rule and change the string, and then the third rule? Or are rules tested against the original string?

Comment: And to clarify more generally: you just want to turn all strings into the form 0W.0X.0Y.Z, correct?

Comment: Kyle - I think sequentially is the way forward

Comment: to answer the second part - I want all of the strings to be in a format that has the structure 99.99.99.99 with all numbers below 10 to have a leading zero. The reason for this is to achieve coherent sorting as at the moment there is no repeatable structure to the data. ideally I would like to break the data into four separate elements and concat later with . separators but that is a little way off yet.

Comment: what version of SSIS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in SSIS 2012 can be achieved with a one-liner Derived Column:

```
RIGHT("00" + TOKEN("1.02.3.04",".",1),2) + "." + RIGHT("00" + TOKEN("1.02.3.04",".",2),2) + "." + RIGHT("00" + TOKEN("1.02.3.04",".",3),2) + "." + RIGHT("00" + TOKEN("1.02.3.04",".",4),2)
```

Comment: Jayvee - almost there that's a brilliant solution the only issue is the output from this derived column does not include the . back into the string. the output is in the form from 1.1.1.1 to 01010101 -

Comment: @JamesK - added the dots please try it now.

Comment: Jayvee - you are a star it works a treat. Just so I understand, this procedure reads in the string up to the first . then adds leading zeros but returns two characters then concatenates in a "." back in - reads in the second occurrence of the . and does the same string manipulation then reads in the third occurrence of the . etc

Comment: @JamesK - yes, that's correct. Token splits the string by "." and we can select any ocurrence. We selected each one, did the leading zeroes bit, then concatenate them back adding the dot in between ocurrences again. If this worked for you, please mark the answer as accepted. Thanks.